# Visual studio 2015 codelens packages?

Tags: visual-studio

I know in VS2013 CodeLens was only available on Ultimate.  I've been using the 2015 preview and I'm wondering about the availability of CodeLens once the product is officially released.  Has there been any info released about whether or not CodeLens is only going to remain a function of Ultimate--or if it will be "dropped down" to other packages, also (i.e. professional or premium)?

Comment: We really can't predict what will or will not be in a product that has not been released yet.  If you cannot be found on the Visual Studio 2015 product pages that exist today then the information has not been released yet.yet.

Comment: Its even more difficult since Microsoft has released what basically amount to a free version of the professional edition of `Visual Studio 2013` with an out of cycle release.  This means its difficult to know what SKUs will even exist for the `Visual Studio 2015` release.  The only version that one can safely estimate will exist is the Ultimate and Community editions of `Visual Studio 2015`.

Comment: @Ramhound Not to be rude, but obviously "we really can't predict" it.  I didn't ask for a prediction, I asked for if there has been any info released that specifically pertains to that.  It's not like a company has never said anything about a product that hasn't made it into a document.

Comment: Do you have the CTP edition? I am able to see codelens features in my version of VS 2015 - CTP. http://i.imgur.com/gXjfhPb.png

Comment: Last year they said they weren't going to change this: see this [link](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/4150271-make-codelens-available-outside-of-ultimate). I don't know if they changed in the meantime.

Answer (score 10):

According to this page (https://www.visualstudio.com/products/compare-visual-studio-2015-products-vs) CodeLens will be available as part of Visual Studio 2015 Pro and higher.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I got this to work:
[CodeLens in VS 2015 CE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33144785/missing-codelens-references-count-in-vs-2015-community-edition/35737320#35737320). I installed the latest SSDT preview for Visual Studio 2015 from the link below on 2 machines I have with VS 2015 Community edition (Update 1), and CodeLens started working for all my projects.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx